# is it good to use UITableViewCell for performance

Tags: objective-c, ios4

i am using UITable View cell for the TableVirewController
its working fine but i want to know one thing,performance wise is it good or writing complete code in
"cellForRowAtIndexPath " method 
which one is better for efficiency

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase and perhaps put in some sample code to illustrate what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the WWDC session "Session 131 - Performance Optimization on iPhone OS", they talked a great deal about how to increase TableView Performance.
Also have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance).