# how to make UITableView scrolling faster?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom cells. Each cell has 2 UIImageView and 2 UILables. I have like a few hundred of these cells.

The scrolling of the table seems to be slower. The images used or not very big in size and are cached.

Is there any way to make it more efficient/faster ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance

Comment: there are multiple techniques to make custom fast-scrolling table-views available online...do some research...google "fast scrolling tableview"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have not used any layer functions for the images or the views.  For example, the layer.cornerRadius property for the images would drastically slow down your scrolling.  There are custom rounded corner functions that won't slow down your table from here http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-uiimage-round-corners/.

I know I'm making guesses, but this can be useful.

Comment: So why did this guy down vote me, maybe is way too unrelated? or just plain bad advice?

Answer (score 0):

i think you added imageView and label  everytime in tableview cell loading, do your cell operation like addSubview  only if(cell==ni) , this will make the scrolling faster

```
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
[cell addSubview:yourImage1];
[cell addSubView:yourImage2];//this will do only if cell first time create .

    }
```

Comment: I am adding the subivews inside the custom cell. I am using a custom cell class.  Do you suggest doing it this way ?

Comment: can you please post what you did in UITableView cellForIndexAtPath methods.., so that i can understand easily