# Objective C - prevent feel of unresponsiveness when clicking a button

Tags: objective-c

What tricks can I do to make my app feel "snappier"?
For example, when I click on a menu button, which loads a different nib file, there is this 1 second delay before the new view shows up, making it feel like the app isn't responsive.

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: related: [Tricks for improving iPhone UITableView scrolling performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance)

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the nib load time by simplifying the content or making some of it load after the view controller appears on-screen.

You can run Instruments on it to try and get an idea of where the choke point is. If it feels unresponsive, compared to other apps, then maybe you're doing something wrong or computationally expensive.

Check that your images are sized correctly. If they're too big that'll up the load time + memory usage.