# Custom UITableViewCell image not showing until scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have an error with my custom `UITableViewCell` image not showing up until the `UITableView` is scrolled. It dosnt happen to all of the cells only the next one comming on or the most recent one comming off (for instane if you see half of the cell on the bottom you cannot see the image until you scroll it all the way into view)

So I have decided that maybe I need to do a better job of relating my `UIImages` to the correct custom cell.

I have created a `UIImageView` called "firstImageView" I then go into my interface builder and relate that to the correct `UIImageView`.

Then inside `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I try to set it like this

```
myCustomCell.firstImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SMILE.png"];
```

However I get this error

> Property 'firstImageView' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To address your error with upcoming images, here is my answer: When you get your `UITableViewCell` like this

```
MyCustomCell *myCustomCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCustomCellIdentifier"];
```

you can implement `-(void)prepareForReuse` method of your override of `UITableViewCell`. Otherwise it is also possible to set the custom content in your `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method after dequeuing your cell.

You can get further information here:
[How to use prepareForUse-Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362713/how-to-use-prepareforreuse-method) and [Apple Documentation of `UITableViewCell`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

To address the other problem with unknown class attribute: What type is your `myCustomCell`? In the interface builder you have to assign the correct type and your `myCustomCell` also has to be of the correct type.

Comment: okay thank you.. going to read up more about prepareForUse.. will it matter that I have several different customer tableviewcells

Comment: For all your custom `UITableViewCell` classes you use you have to implement this method. It is called when `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is called.

Comment: This is not true. I've made plenty of projects with custom cells, and never implemented this method. He probably didn't change the class of the cell to his subclass, which is why the error is saying UITableViewCell rather than what ever his class is.

Comment: damn I cannot figure it out.. I would love for someone to check out my tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method but I am working on a sensitive project I dont want to post alot of its details on the net...

Comment: @rdelmar It depends on your cell initialization. When you initialize a cell with `[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"someReuseIdentifier"]` or with `[someTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifier"]` makes the difference. In the first case you are initializing a new cell and the reuse identifier is not used. In the latter case you dequeue a cell with a given reuse identifier, thus, a cell is reused and you have to set the new custom content, e.g. a custom image.

Comment: @HurkNburkS Can you post only the important content of the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method where you initialize the cell?

Comment: Yes, you have to set the new custom content, but it doesn't HAVE to be done in prepareForReuse as you said. There's no problem with doing it in cellForRowAtIndexPath -- doing it there is not what the OP's problem is.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It does not have to be done in the `prepareForeReuse` method. I will change this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

here 122,111 are  THE frames for image view in table view cell replace it with yours                                                                          ``
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO,UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);                                                                          `˚˚`CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(122,111);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

Answer (score 0):

When dequeueing the cell are you casting it as your custom cell class?

```
MyCustomCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass but you don't dequeue it using the Identifier you assigned in IB ("reuse identifier")..