# Clear cached cells from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

To establish some context :
I have a UITableView with n cells.
When the user selects a cell they the cell expands and the user experience then continues within that cell. 
There are some animations that take place within the cell.

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
     //expand cell/increase cell height animated
     //add a button to bottom of cell with target(didpressbutton:)
}

- (void)didpressbutton:(id)sender
{
     //perform complex animating rearranging UI elements
}
```

At the end of the flow the user needs to comeback to the original tableview.

But the cell with the misaligned UI elements are still showing as it is dequeuing the old cells.
Is there any way for me to clear the cached cell or reinitialise them?

Comment: "the user experience then continues within that cell" how does that work ? Can you post some code ?

Comment: How about not using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier method in cellforRowAtIndexPath? But it contains memory problem,meybe.

Answer (score 0):

> But the cell with the misaligned UI elements are still showing as it is dequeuing the old cells.
>   Is there any way for me to clear the cached cell or reinitialise them?

You are obviously misusing `-prepareForReuse:`. Implement this method to reset any state the cells have.

Comment: I tried this, but to no success, it's possible I'm doing something wrong.
Has this worked for you ?

Comment: I don't know what your cell does. But it has always worked for me. Can you provide your implementation of `-prepareForReuse:` ?

Comment: wait, do I have to implement it ?
I though I would just have to call it

Comment: based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362713/how-to-use-prepareforreuse-method
I would have to reset all the views manually

Comment: @AatishMolasi It gets called automatically by `UITableView`. You have to implement it in your cell subclass and reset it's state. Apple can't know what they need to reset in your custom class, hence you need to tell them.

Comment: ah, that's what I was hoping I would not have to do, but just delete this cell and reinitialise another one

Comment: You can force cells to not get reused by not passing a `reuseIdentifier` during creation.

Comment: But then I will reinstantiate  every cell every time, not something I would like to do

Comment: @AatishMolasi Then go and implement -prepareForReuse? You will need to do one or the other.