# Setting a colour for a particular cell in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to set the background colour of particular cells in UITableViewCell to purple.

So far, I've tried this and it sets the colour of all the cells to purple instead of only the first cell.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
for(int k = 0; k < queueMCDate.count; k++){
    if(_qbColorArr.count == 0) {

    }
    else if ([[_qbColorArr objectAtIndex:k]  isEqual:@"a"]) {
        if(indexPath.row == k)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.04 blue:0.41 alpha:1.0];
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Here's a link showing how it currently looks right now.

[image: Link]

How I would want the app to work is, after setting the return dates in the first cell, I would want it to be purple. By,
 assigning a string value of `a` to them, when I set the return dates, I was hoping that it would work.

---

Edit:

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
QueueDetails *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.queueNo.text = fQueueNo[indexPath.row];
cell.queueeName.text = queueNameDisp[indexPath.row];
cell.bkTitle.text = queueBk[indexPath.row];
cell.dateRe.text = queueRDate[indexPath.row];
cell.dateBo.text = queueBDate[indexPath.row];

for(int k = 0; k < queueRDate.count; k++){
    if(_qbColorArr.count == 0) {
         cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
         return cell;
    }
    else if ([[_qbColorArr objectAtIndex:k]  isEqual:@"a"]) {
        if(indexPath.row == k)
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.04 blue:0.41 alpha:1.0];
            return cell;
        else{
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            return cell;
        }
    }
}


}
```

The cells would be at default white at the start, however when a return date is added to a cell, that cell would need to turn purple, indicating that a book has been returned, whilst the others stayed white.

To better clarify, the reason I used `_qbColorArr` was because that the array contains either a blank (initialized at `viewDidLoad`) or `a`. So, when I set a return date to the first cell, I've also done this `[_qbColorArr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"a"]`. This would then would be checked at the `else if` statement and assign the color of the cell to purple.

Comment: what kind of design of tableview cell you require ?

Comment: The cells would be white at the start, however when a return date is added to a cell, the cell would need to turn purple, indicating that a book has been returned.

Comment: upload full snapcode of tableview  cellrowatindexpath delegate method

Comment: else if ([[_qbColorArr objectAtIndex:k]  isEqual:@"a"]) {
        if(indexPath.row == k)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.04 blue:0.41 alpha:1.0];
        else{
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
    } in this method return your cell remove at last

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but ended up with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the default color in the else condition. Once the color of row is set to purple, then because of reuse-identifier the color remains unchanged. Set the default color as follows:-

```
for(int k = 0; k < queueMCDate.count; k++){
    if(_qbColorArr.count == 0) {
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//Your Default Color will go here 
    }
    else if ([[_qbColorArr objectAtIndex:k]  isEqual:@"a"]) {
        if(indexPath.row == k)
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.04 blue:0.41 alpha:1.0];
        else{
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//Your Default Color will go here
        }
    }
}

return cell;
```

Comment: Or you could use the `prepareForReuse` method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, it still displayed the same result.

Comment: @Arshad I have updated the if condition too. Check updated answer. Set the default color in all other conditions. 
Also you can use the [prepareForResuse method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269169/988169).

Comment: I tried both your updated answer and the prepareForReuse method, both resulted in the same problem. I've also updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't really understand your question... As what in your description, I will think if cell.dateRe.text is nothing then your cell will be white color and purple color otherwise.

So just give a try.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
QueueDetails *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.queueNo.text = fQueueNo[indexPath.row];
cell.queueeName.text = queueNameDisp[indexPath.row];
cell.bkTitle.text = queueBk[indexPath.row];
cell.dateRe.text = queueRDate[indexPath.row];
cell.dateBo.text = queueBDate[indexPath.row];

if (cell.dateRe.text.length > 0){
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.48 green:0.04 blue:0.41 alpha:1.0];
} else{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
return cell;
}
```