# UITableView with matrix view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

i wanted to know what's the best approach to develop such an "epg matrix" as the ONAIR iPad app is showing? I think it will be a tableview with scrollable cells or something like that?

[image]

Has anyone an idea how to get started or can provide some examples/tutorials/sample code on this?

Would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: How about using custom cells with scrollViews, if cells can be scrolled individually? If everything scrolls together, just put your entire tableview(with a width greater than the screen's) in a scrollview

Comment: yes, it should scroll all together. the only question is how to load the cells dynamically when you scroll horizontally to the right side..

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance/1352594#1352594) to draw cells dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fact i think the onair App uses three Scrollviews:
- a small one at the top thats showing the time (scrollable left/right)
- the one on the left side showing the tv-stations (scrollable up/down)
- and the big one on which the programs are presented (scrollable in every direction)

And you have to link the scrolling of the uiscrollviews in their delegates (which should be the same (super-)viewcontroller) uiscrollview:didscroll method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1

Comment: thx, but i think in the ONAIR app it's only a scrollview with vertical and horizontal scrolling.. but anyway, thank you.

if somebody else has an idea, please let me know.