# Tappable elements in a UITableViewCell composed of a single view

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

A lot of advice is given telling people to to consolidate a UITableViewCell into a single view. I'm wondering how to do that and still retain tappable elements, like they do in apps such as Tweetbot.

Comment: Where are those advices given?

Comment: For example, in multiple places here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be [NSAttributedStrings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

These a bit tricky to handle, but wrapper classes exist as open source as for example [TTTArrtibutedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)

The thread you link to names the article "Fast Scrolling in Tweetie with UITableView". This article isn't online anymore, but some [github projects](https://github.com/dongsheng/fastscrolling), that call them selfs to be compliant to the article.
Actually it seems to be the trick, that UIView subclasses use `-drawRect:` to to draw themselves. To use tap-able strings, see NSAttributedStrings.

PS:
Thanks the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100922230053/http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/), you can read the article, actually it is description of the GitHub project.

Answer (score 0):

I do it by form of delegation. That view defines a protocol which the tableView's controller conforms to. Set the controller as the view's delegate and when an area is tapped, send the correct message.