# Better to use a small image that resizes or true sized image for UITableViewCell background?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to address a slow scrolling and slow loading UIViewController that uses a UITableView with custom background cells.

When I don't set the backgroundView of the cell with an image, the performance is great. So I'm wondering if it's more performant to supply the backgroundView with images that are the actual size of my tableview row or is it better to use smaller images that are resized to fit the row's dimensions?

The images are all local and already included in the app - there's no remote fetching involved.

[Improving load time of UITableView that has cells with custom background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361190/improving-viewcontroller-load-speed-with-custom-uitableviewcells-a-broken-recor)

Answer (score 0):

Try to look to use an [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) to handle lazy loading of images and a custom tableviewcell.
Google for tweetie custom tableviewcell That should set you in the right direction.

Apple has a sample project for downloading images in tableViews: [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: The images already local and built into the project - no downloading is necessary. I'm curious and interested in finding out the general best practice for doing this.

Comment: Do you have single image for all the cell or different images for each cell?

Comment: 3 different images, 1 per row type.