# Most efficient way to hide a UIView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uitableview

Out of the following, which is the best way to hide a view?

- Setting frame to CGRectZero
- Hidden Property to YES
- alpha Property to 0.0

Does one have benefits that the other does not? In terms of saving resources at runtime? Specifically in a UITableView with reusable cells where some subviews may not be needed by one cell versus another.

Comment: Could you please provide more context? The three things are vastly different.

Comment: hidden would be the best one for sure. alpha to 0 it is expensive. rect zero is just messy..

Comment: @dasblinkenlight added more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want/need to accomplish. For views that will likely be reused alot, a combination of `view.hidden=TRUE` (my choice for this case) and/or `view.alpha=0.0`, and maybe manipulate the z-index to make sure your view is no longer at the front.

I am not sure about the benefit of setting the view's frame to `CGRectZero`, it might be more appropriate to remove the entirely at that point.

In short, if you don't need it, don't keep it.

**UPDATE**:

With the mention table cells, also consider the possibility of creating multiple [custom cells](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/), especially if removing subviews causes layout problems. Each cell can be created based on whatever criteria you have set.

**UPDATE 2**:

Based on a comment left below, if the cells are complex, drawing the cell via code may be the right solution.

Comment: Actually, although I like using custom cells in IB, it's a bad idea if you have a performance bottleneck. Complex cells are best done with no subviews at all, via `drawRect`. This question has more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance

Comment: @lxt Again, it all depends on one's needs.

Answer (score 0):

With UIView's, `alpha=0` has the advantage of being animatable whereas `hidden=YES` does not. `frame=CGRectZero` is also animatable but is quite a different effect. When animating `alpha=0.0` will cause the view to fade out whereas `frame=CGRectZero` will cause it to appear to vanish into the upper left. I wouldn't worry about the system resource expense of any of these techniques as they're all pretty lightweight.

Comment: if you need to animate and fade out you can indeed go to alpha 0, but then in the completion block i would set hidden=YES as well, to avoid drawing a non visible view