# UICollectionView: Smooth scrolling with many visible cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to optimize the scrolling speed and smoothness of my `UICollectionView` (using a custom layout) that has about 400 cells, 150 of which are visible on the screen at the same time.

The cells themselves aren't very complex: They consist of a (fully opaque) colored background and two labels (with the same background color).

So far, I've read dozens of posts on optimizing speed by

- properly reusing cells,
- avoiding transparency in all backgrounds,
- avoiding box shadows,
- avoiding corner radius, and
- avoiding fractional cell positions and sizes.

Despite all these optimizations, I still can't scroll smoothly with 60 fps. I've also tried layer rasterization (`shouldRasterize`) after dequeuing cells, but that had a negative impact on performance.

Reducing the amount of cells that are visible at the same time is the only thing that improved performance — scrolling is totally smooth with fewer cells. Unfortunately, that's not an option.

What else can I do to get close to 60 fps with many `UICollectionViewCell`s visible at once?

Answer (score 3):

If you have shadows on cell, check if using `shouldRasterize` on the cells layer could improve the framerate.
Also, never do blocking actions inside the `- collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method

Answer (score 1):

The `UICollectionView` behaves much like the `UITableView`

Use this link for a reference : [UITableView Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance)

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, I had a similar problem, it was down to cornerRadius on the cell and the UIView within the cell. I was able to remove it from the cell and still keep the asthetic I was looking for with the cornerRadius on the UIView. End result smooth scrolling.