# IOS9 uitableview scrolling is jerky

Tags: uitableview, ios9

Since IOS9, the scrolling of the uitableview of my application is jerky. I use customcell which have to slow down the display but I had no problem on ios8. Have you the same thing?

After investigation , creating UIImage freezes scrolling. Are there behavioral changes in IOS9 UIImage ?

Comment: What does your uiimage code within the cell look like?

Comment: self.someImageView.image = UIImage(named: "some_image")

Comment: yeah, perfs with uitableview/uicollectionview since iOS9 are shit... a lot of layout says the time profiler.

Comment: Is there an alternative solution for creating complex uitableview / uicollectionview ?

Comment: Anyone else experience a similar problem? I've got custom cells that really struggle on an iphone 6, as @Vinzius mentioned, with about 100 percent time spent on layout in the profiler. I wonder what could cause this and how to fix it, as my own classes are not in the stack. Is it the images? Those loaded from the bundle are static after the first configuration and don't get modified after that; others are from core data and initialized with NSData objects. Was no problem before iOS 9.

Comment: I suggest you to load images async and dispatch the setImage on the main thread. In my case I cached the placeholders (always the same images) in an array...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your problem is but here a few different things you can try that might make your scrolling smoother:

1. Be careful of the size of your `UIImage`'s, if you have multiple large photos in your `UITableView` it might cause it to not have smooth scrolling. I personally export my photos so that they are around a few hundred KB each.
2. Load your `UITableView` and `UIImage`'s in the `viewDidLoad` method if you aren't already. Otherwise you might be loaded them as you are scrolling.

Also refer to this [Tricks for improving iPhone UITableView scrolling performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance) for some more ways to improve your `UITableView` scrolling.